# How do I create a python code that distinguishes between the capital of a state and the state that the capital has?

Tags: python, file, csv

I have an excel file that has all of the states and their capitals called "state_capitals.csv"

```
filename= r"c:\users\Marissa\Documents"
dirname=filename
filename=dirname + "\state_capitals.csv"
data=open(filename).read()
print(data)
file=open(filename)
dir(file)
lines=data.splitlines()
first_line=lines[0]
first_line.split(",")
```

But I don't know how to create code that can tell that the capital of New York is Albany or that the capital named Madison belongs to Wisconsin

I need to define a function that given the name of a state, looks up the state capital.  I also need to define a function that given the name of a capital, looks up the corresponding state.  If a match is not found, then I want to return None.

However, I cannot figure out the correct way to do this..Can I define a function and still prompt a user to enter a state or capital name or did I need to do it differently?

Here is a sample of the data inside of the file:

```
Maine,Augusta
Maryland,Annapolis
Massachusetts,Boston
Michigan,Lansing
Minnesota,St. Paul
Mississippi,Jackson
Missouri,Jefferson City
Montana,Helena
Nebraska,Lincoln
Nevada,Carson City
New Hampshire,Concord
New Jersey,Trenton
New Mexico,Santa Fe
New York,Albany
North Carolina,Raleigh
North Dakota,Bismarck
Ohio,Columbus
```

Comment: Neither can we unless you tell us what's in the file. Is it just two fields, state and capital?

Comment: Can you show us a few rows of data? Btw, if your data does not tell you this, Python will not. Python is not *that* magical.

Comment: And how should the program work? Read queries on standard input?

Comment: @pnuts yeah... it **was** :) Re-opened...

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
data = open("state_capitals.csv").read()
state_name = raw_input("Enter State Name:")
print re.findall(".*%s.*"%(state_name,),data,re.I)
```

probably